# I want to create a table and select the value using row and column using python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having a table in the paper. that is

```
 name   age  dob     address
arvindh 12   4-1-78  12, abc street 
ajay    34   3-6-52  23. xyz street
```

consider name as row and age, dob and address as the column.
For example, when I gave input as arvindh and age(the column name), I am in need of the output 12. here name is unique value.

I didn't need a code. Please share me the package or the logic using python to get the above output and that table should be in my code. I tried the python pandas library to use the table but I am unable to get it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use ```pandas```. read the csv (already built-in ```read_csv``` functionality inside), create a dataframe and filter as you'de like..

Comment: Is there any reason not to use something like pandas? Otherwise you're going to want to look into what type of structure you want to store your data in. You could do a nested dictionary (json style), or nested lists if you're masochistic etc

Comment: What does 'having a table in the paper' mean?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. 1. Values are not in the form of CSV. 2. The nested dictionary is best I think. Now I am trying on it. 3. paper means I have the table in the written format of the paper using ink and pen

Comment: "age" may be a column name, but "arvindh" isn't a row name.it's a value in the column named "name" — so it's unclear what you mean by "select the value using row and column".

Comment: What do you mean by "that table should be in my code"? What code?

Comment: That table of values. arvindh is value in the column you are right. arvindh and age as input and 12 as output. That is I want. It is clear now? If you understood, provide me the logic or package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically you want to know how to create a dataframe? Try this snippet:

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {'name': ['arvidh', 'ajay'], 'age': [12, 34], 'dob': ['4-1-78', '3-6-52'], 'address': ['12, abc street', '23, xyz street']}

# specifying the columns makes sure they are in the desired order
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict, columns=['name', 'age', 'dob', 'address'])

print(df)
```

This should print:

```
     name  age     dob         address
0  arvidh   12  4-1-78  12, abc street
1    ajay   34  3-6-52  23, xyz street
```

You can access an individual entry by specifying the column and the index, like so:

```
print(df['name'][0])
```

Returns

```
arvidh
```

EDIT:

If you want the reverse search, you can get the indices this way:

```
# column of the attribute you search, e.g. 'age' prints 1
df.columns.get_loc('age')

# index(es) of row that has the correct name as list, prints [0]
df.index[df['name'] == 'arvidh'].tolist()
```

Comment: Thanks, DocDriven, it is perfect and now I understood the data frame also. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @AravindhThirumaran: you are welcome, I added the reverse search just in case.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
############## Read in excel file ##########################
col1 = ['arvindh', 'ajay']
col2 = [12, 34]
col3 = ['4-1-78', '3-6-52']
col4 = ['12, abc street', '23. xyz street']


df = pd.DataFrame()
df['name'] = col1
df['age'] = col2
df['dob'] = col3
df['address'] = col4

########################################################
```

Pandas

```
import pandas as pd

keyword = 'arvindh'
print (df[df['name'] == keyword]['age'])
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer @chitown88